# rails refinery added to existing site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I have added refinery to an existing site, pointed it to /blog.  I was able create my first user, everything looks like it works except for two things.

First, there are not wysiwyg editor visible, just a text area.

And when I try to show a page created I get an error when rendering my current site nav bar.  It looks like the render is not seeing my routes, but I have no idea why.

Here are the pertinent details...

No WYSIWYG...

[image]

error when rendering page...

```
undefined local variable or method `profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc124046798>:0x000000085997c0>
```

Extracted source:

```
%li= link_to 'Profiles', profiles_path
```

All other pages of the existing site work with the nav just fine, it is only when trying to render a CMS generated page.

Comment: Do you see your profiles path when you run `rake:routes`

Comment: yes and when I am on any of the existing app pages it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the wysiwyg problem was to install refinerycms-wymeditor

The solution to the profiles_path route issue was to prefix all of my nav and footer links with "main_app."